# Not getting the exact data after rendering it from child component in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const data = [
  {
    class: "Pre Nursery",
    sections: ["a"]
  },
  {
    class: "Nursery",
    sections: ["b"]
  },
  {
    class: "1",
    sections: ["a", "b"]
  }
];
```

Given above is the data array.

```
const subjects = ()=>{
data.map((item, i) => {
            return (
                   <div class="row border pb-3" key={i+1}>
                       <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
                               <input type="checkbox" class="W-3" id="" />
                               <label htmlFor="" class="mx-2 fs2">{item.class}</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
                                   <Editsubjects class={item.class}/>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                  )
            }
}
```

In the above code, I'm using the map to loop over the data, I'm passing the class value of every object of the array in the Editsubjects component.

```
const Editsubjects = (props) =>{
          return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="popup">   
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger mt-1 W-100" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                    Edit Subjects
                </button>
                {/* Modal */}
                <div class="modal fade " id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header d-block justify-content-start align-items-start text-align-start">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit subjects for sections</h5>
                                <p>
                                    <h6>Selected class: {props.class}</h6>

                                </p>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Whenever I'm rendering the Editsubjects component and clicking the Edit subjects button I'm only getting the value of the class key of the 0th index in the data array. Like I'm only getting the selected subjects as pre Nursery(Selected class: Pre Nursery) for every rendered Edit subject button I click.

I want to render the value of the class key of every index in the array in the Editsubjects component. Can anyone please tell me what my code is doing and what will be its solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what framework you're using here (seems to be bootstrap), but I guess it uses the modal's ID which in your case is always `exampleModal`. The target is always `data-bs-target="#exampleModal"`. Rendering your list, you get multiple elements with this ID and it will return the first one if asked for it (what I assume will occur in the background). So it will always open the first (0) modal

Comment: You're rendering three modals that all have `id="exampleModal"`. That is invalid HTML, and your button will only show the first one. However the usual solution is also out of the window because you're using React. You need to switch your approach to a React one. Use this instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap, docs here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#live-demo (since you might fall into the same trap: you will need a separate `isOpen` state for each modal or pass the array index so the modal loads the appropriate content.)

Comment: Yaa that's worked for me